# Create frames based on number of items in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tkinter

So I have a list:

```
titles = ["Crazy", "Delusional", "Perfection", "IDK"]
```

Using `tkinter` I want to create frames in different row and column based on number of items in a list `titles`, with the text in each frame (text will be from a list, each frame will get one text from elements in a list, so for example frame 1 will have text "Crazy" in it, frame 2 will have text "Delusional" in it...).

In this example, there should be a total of four frames created, but if the number of elements changes, so `titles` becomes:

```
titles = ["Crazy", "Delusional", "Perfection", "IDK", "Who Knows"]
```

There should be five frames in total.

Comment: Are you asking us to write the code for you? What part of the problem do you need help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with ease in a loop:

something like this for instance: (this keeps a reference to the frames in a list, but not of the labels)

```
import tkinter as tk

titles = ["Crazy", "Delusional", "Perfection", "IDK", "Who Knows"]

root = tk.Tk()
frames = [tk.Frame(root) for _ in range(len(titles))]
for frame, title in zip(frames, titles):
    tk.Label(frame, text=title).pack()
    frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

or with a class:  (this one doesn't keep a reference to the frames or the labels, but you could.)

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, titles):
        super().__init__()
        self.titles = titles[:]   # copy the titles
        for title in self.titles:
            f = tk.Frame(self)
            tk.Label(f, text=title).pack()
            f.pack()


titles = ["Crazy", "Delusional", "Perfection", "IDK", "Who Knows"]
App(titles).mainloop()
```